# Neoclassical Neologisms

Tags: latin, neologisms, greek

Could anybody give me a few interesting examples of neologisms of Latin or Greek origin, or containing affixes from Latin or Greek which are popular nowadays but haven't entered the dictionaries yet? There are quite plenty of examples in The Oxford Dictionary of New Words from 1999 for instance, but I am interested in the ones which are not in the dictionary but still very popular nowadays. Thanks

Comment: To clarify: do you want us to identify *existing* neologisms for you, or coin *new* ones, in this thread? I ask because though at face value, either of those questions is off-topic on StackExchange (the first for being "too broad", the second for being too subjective, or what we call "primarily opinion-based"), the first kind of question can be brought on-topic and provided with helpful, high-quality answers, if it is narrowed down a little. What kinds of neologism are you seeking? What kinds of concepts should they express? What is the background, aka motivation, behind, this question?

Comment: I can't be bothered to look it up, but I seem to remember that ***television*** contains both Latin *and* Greek elements. And by its very nature, it's pretty much bound to be a "neologism". But the question here is Too Broad. There will be *thousands* of such words.

Comment: @DanBron ,Thank you all for your answers and feedback, it's helpful because I'm new here. In order to clarify my question I would say that I seek for the new neologisms which haven't entered the dictionaries yet. I can find the 'existing' ones in The Oxford Dictionary of New Words from 1999 for instance, but there are still new words which are, let's say popular, and not quite accepted yet in the dictionaries. I hope I clarified my question more precisely.

Comment: Suggesting migration to meta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Wikipedia's category of neologisms from 2010](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Words_coined_in_the_2010s), as of this writing, includes 18 words.  Of those, three seem to derive more-or-less directly from Latin and/or Greek roots.

Cissexism: From the Latin *cis-*, meaning "on this side of", and *sexism*, itself eventually from the Latin *sexus*, meaning "division" or "sex", and the Greek *-ismos*, which constructs an abstract noun from a verb.

Misogynoir: From misogyny, itself from the Greek roots *miseo*, "I hate", and *gune*, "woman", blended with *noir*, eventually from the Latin *niger*, meaning "black".

Sexposition: A blend of *sex* (as described above) and *exposition*, eventually from the Latin *ex-*, "out" (cognate with the Greek *eks-*, by the way), and the Latin *pono*, "put, place".

Based on a quick glance at [Wikipedia's category of neologisms from the 2000s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Words_coined_in_the_2000s), the ratio of words more-or-less directly from Latin and Greek roots looks about the same.

[I don't have the reputation to include all the researched links in my answer.  I included them in a comment below.]

Comment: The links:


Cissexism: [cis-](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cis-), [sexus](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sexus#Latin), [-ismos](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-%CE%B9%CF%83%CE%BC%CF%8C%CF%82#Ancient_Greek)


Misogynoir: [miseo](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CE%BC%CE%B9%CF%83%CE%AD%CF%89#Ancient_Greek), [gune](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CE%B3%CF%85%CE%BD%CE%AE#Ancient_Greek), [niger](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/niger#Latin)


Sexposition: [ex-](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ex#Latin), [pono](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pono#Latin)